# Start threads instead of calling method

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got problem with threads. I have drawing methods in class `Floor` which draw wolf and hares in the appropriate locations, and there is the animation method in this class. I can't write drawing methods in `Hare` and `Wolf` class, but I want to change the image after a move. I've made something like that, I haven't wanted to give threads yet, because they aren't made appropriate, I have only `move()` method written in thread's `run()` method in `Wolf` and `Hare` classes, but something has to be added there. All I want is to be like in the code below, so every animal moves 20 times, and after every move there is a `repaint()` method called, but with two changes: every animal "lifes its own life" - moves with a different pause between them, and there is a `start()` method called instead of `move()` one.

I can't set `wait()` method and `yield()` in a right way, that's my problem.

```
public void animation()
    {

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e){}

                wolf.move();
                repaint();

            for(Hare i: hares){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch( InterruptedException e){}

                i.move();
                repaint();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think you should google "game loop".